# Error upgrading rails from 5.0.0.rc1 to 5.0.0.rc2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, upgrade

OS: Mac OS X El-Captain
current rails version: 5.0.0.rc1
ruby version: 2.3.1p112

I'm having following error. Googling and searching on Stack Overflow didn't give any results.

**gem install rails -v 5.0.0.rc2**

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Resolver::Molinillo::CircularDependencyError)
    There is a circular dependency between camping and rack
```

Comment: Post whole an error message

Comment: That's whole error message

Comment: It's strange. Because I have exactly the same environment and it works. You can try to remove all gems and instal rails first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to uninstall my version of Ruby (2.3.1) and re-install. Then running `gem install rails --pre` worked.

I use rbenv and ruby-build. The instructions for removing Ruby are found here, https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#uninstalling-ruby-versions.

Comment: Thanks. Worked! :) but I after re-installing ruby `2.3.1` and ran `gem install rails -v 5.0.0.rc2`.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be related to out of date system gems. I encountered it installing bundler. I cleared it by entering :

gem update --system

I can install latest ruby, bundler, rails, and all works fine.

I'm running OS X 10.11.6.

Best, 
John